# What is the a performance cost of Django's unique_together feature

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-models

To me it seems like there would be a lot of processing or searching when using more complex `unique_together` tuples. It seems like the better option would be to strictly handle uniqueness when creating records in a database. Does anyone happen to know what the costs are to using `unique_together` especially if they involve more complex tuples?

I currently have a model that I will likely need to switch from

```
index_together = unique_together = (('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'd'))
```

to

```
index_together = unique_together = (('a', 'b', 'e'), ('a', 'c', 'd', 'e'))
```

Comment: What do you mean, "strictly handle uniqueness"? Isn't that what unique_together does?

Comment: I meant strictly handle uniqueness by checking for a record that fits the intended criteria. If `ModelName.objects.get(a=a, b=b, e=e)` update the record, otherwise create a new record.  Of course, this method has some definite drawbacks, the biggest I can see being that you'd need to make sure that this sort of check is performed everywhere that a record could be created, it's probably a bit more obvious than `unique_together`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unique_together` is implemented as `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` at the database level. Read how SQL indexes work, about read / write ratio (indexes are built when data is written, so it slows down write operations but when there is much more of reads than writes that is not the problem), read about index selectivity / cardinality. Use `EXPLAIN` queries to check whether the index are used (not ignored) when retrieving data.

Having multiple large unique indexes is one of the sign that the table should be split into two or few with lower number of columns, related through one to many relations.